# Extracting data from text file after 2 conditions have been met

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

I'm working on a bash script at the moment which extracts data from a text file called `carslist.txt`, which each car (and its corresponding characteristics) being on separate lines. I've been able to extract and save data from the text file after it's met a single condition (below for example) but I can't figure out how to do it for two conditions.

Single condition example:

`grep 'Vauxhall' $CARFILE > output/Vauxhall_Cars.txt`

output:

```
Vauxhall:Vectra:1999:White:2
Vauxhall:Corsa:1999:White:5
Vauxhall:Cavalier:1995:White:2
Vauxhall:Nova:1994:Black:8
```

From the examples above, how would I extract data if I wanted the conditions `Vauxhall` and `White` to be met before extracting them?

the grep example above asks for `Vauxhall` to be met before pulling and saving the data, but I have no idea how to do it for 2. I've tried pipelining the command as `Vauxhall | White` but after that I was out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `grep '^Vauxhall:' $CARFILE | grep ':White:'`

Comment: Seems to be creating a the output file but not saving any of the data, any idea why that might be?

Comment: grep writes to stdout, just redirect it to your output filename ( `.. 1>youroutput.txt;` )

Comment: I've been writing it to output/saveFile.txt but it's just an empty file

Comment: is $CARFILE defined in the context you call it in..

Comment: Yup, sorry I haven't put the full bash script in the post. It's defined before anything else and I've been using it throughout the script successfully.

Comment: so test like `grep '^Vauxhall:' carslist.txt | grep ':White:' 1>output/Vauxhall_Cars.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use `awk`, like this:

```
awk -F: '$1=="Vauxhall" && $4=="White"' input.file
```

As I'm using `:` as the field separator, I simply need to check the values of field 1 and 4.

Comment: Would you then use `> output.file` at the end to save the extracted data?

Comment: Yes, if you need the output saved to a file. But don't use `> $CARFILE`, meaning don't redirect to the input file itself, since this would lead to an empty file.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to run it and the script just pauses completely and only finishes if I `ctrl + D` out. I've ran the script with tracing and it's freezing. Here's the completed line: `awk -F: '$1=="Volkswagen" && $4=="Blue"' $CARLIST > output/Blue_Volkswagen.txt`, is that correctly formatted?

Comment: If it freezes then the variable `$CARLIST` is empty, meaning it reads from stdin. Please make sure that `$CARLIST` will contain a valid filename.

Comment: Oh god I'm an idiot. My variable was $CARFILE not $CARLIST. Thanks, that's working perfectly.